# JQuery doesn't work after a minute or two

Tags: javascript, jquery

My JQuery works well to allow the logo to pop up the mobile navigation but it doesn't work after a few minutes. It no longer changes the display of the UL when the logo is clicked Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  checkSize();
});

function checkSize(){
  if ($("ul, #left img:nth-of-type(2)").css("display") == "none" ) {
    $("#click").on('click',function() {
      $("ul, #left img:nth-of-type(2)").toggleClass("show-items");
    });
  }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you've re-created `$("#click")` using `.html()` or `innerHTML`, hence the original element doesn't exist, and the event is not attached to a new element. With the provided code we can't reproduce your issue.

Comment: Thanks Teemu. Your comment to another question was exactly what I was looking for. Using the click event in the $(document).ready()

Answer (score 2):

[From jQuery docs](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/):

> Code included inside $( document ).ready() will only run once the page
>   Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute.

Your jQuery works, only you have specified to run it once.

UPDATE:

To run your script every time the window changes size use `.resize()`

> The resize event is sent to the window element when the size of the
>   browser window changes:

```
// run once the document is lodaded
$(document).ready(checkSize);

// run on resize
$( window ).resize(checkSize);
```

Comment: How do I specify it to run again and again?

Comment: What kind of behavior do you want? When do you want to run checkSize()?

Comment: I want checkSize() to run when the viewport width is <= 500px.

Comment: @AlexanderWylde Why? It looks like the function attaches the click listener only, you should not attach that listener multiple times. If the function does something you're not showing in the example, attach the click listener directly in the `$(document).ready`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean onclick event didn't working?
How many times you call checkSize() function?
May be you call it couple of times - so you bind couple onclick events. 
And may be you call `$("ul, #left img:nth-of-type(2)").toggleClass("show-items");` twice - so it toggle class twice. And it's looks like as "no effect".

Use `debugger;` in the first line of the onclick event and look in the developer tool how many times this event will be raised.

Also you can add `$("#click").off('click');` before binding this event.